# How to query complex range in postgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns in my one postgreSQL Table.

The name of columns are: TO, FROM
which denotes a range. Let say 100 - 200 (so here 100 will save in TO and 200 will get saved in FROM)

Now, the main problem is any number in this range will be never be used again. i.e we can't save (100,101,102...200 according to the example mentioned above).

I have to create a query in which I have to take data from the request and check whether the requested range is in the database or not.

Example: 100 -200 are already saved in database and I am getting request of following:
1) 100 -200
2) 150-250
3) 20 -150
4) 50 -280
e.t.c...
All the above cases are false because at least one number is already saved in db

I am new to SQL can you please help in querying? I am using postgreSQL.

Comment: Isn't it that FROM is 100 and 200 is TO, not the other way round?

Comment: But other ranges. Let say 150- 250 also contains 50 numbers (From 150 to 200 ) which are already put into the database. Am I right?

Comment: You don't actually need a query to check for that. In Postgres you can create an exclusion constraint that will automatically prevent the insert of overlapping ranges

Comment: Testing for overlapping ranges in any language requires just two conditions if your ranges are in the right order (start <= end): `end2 >= start1 && end1>= start2`

Comment: Yes I have also made a query (FROM <= Req.from AND TO >= Req.from) OR
(FROM <= Req.to AND To >= Req.to) OR
(FROM >= Req.from AND To <= Req.to). But is there any other better way to do it ?

Comment: I am storing ranges in random order. That's why it has become complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 
(dateFrom <= Req.from AND dateTo >= Req.from)OR
(dateFrom <= Req.to AND dateTo >= Req.to) OR
(dateFrom >= Req.from AND dateTo <= Req.to)
```

I didn't find better then this

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has [range functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html). Did yo look at it? So you can use the overlap operator for example to check whether ranges, well, overlap.

```
int8range(3,7) && int8range(4,12)
```

Comment: Sure Let me check it.